# How to make pagebreak spread the paragraphs in scrartcl

Tags: spacing, page-breaking

Using *scractcl* (or *article*), I would like a page break via `\pagebreak` to have the same effect (of spreading the paragraphs evenly across the page) as in document class *book*. I couldn't find this anywhere on TexSE. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for `\flushbottom`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: That worked, but do I have to put it before every `\pagebreak`, or is there a way to make this behavior universal for the entire document.

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Oops, sorry, I guess I mistunderstood the behavior of `\flushbottom`. Why don't you make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\flushbottom` in the preamble (article uses by default `\raggedbottom`).